# CSS Dropdown Menu issue in Chrome

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu, positioning

I am designing a website using a CSS drop down menu (as an include to the site pages).  What SHOULD happen is when you hover over a menu item a dropdown box will appear with choices that you can then drag your mouse down to select.  It works fine in IE and Firefox, but in Chrome when you hover over a menu item and go to drag your mouse down, a container div (that is no where near where your mouse is hovering) overlaps the drop down box and it disappears.  I noticed the div when clicking view source in Chrome.  I have attached the CSS for the drop down menu and a link to the drop down menu include.

The CSS that I believe to be the problem is the #banner class which holds a logo, a title, and a login form.  I have it set so #bannerContainer holds #banner so that it can be centered on any screen resolution (see code below).   Any help to this problem would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

CSS:  http://bridgedeck.org/newsite/pro_dropdown_n1.css

```
#bannercontainer { /* centers banner items on any screen resolution */
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
width:100%;
height:105px;
z-index:2000;
background-image: url(images/bannerOrigBlue.png);
```

}

```
#banner { /* Holds wheel, mmp text and members login form*/
position:relative;
width:1000px;
height:100px;
z-index:0;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
```

}

HTML:

```
<div id="bannercontainer">
<div id="banner"> <!-- holds wheel, MMP text, and members login -->
    <a href="http://www.bridgedeck.org/newsite"><img src="images/wheellogocolor2.png" height="140" width="140"></a>
    <img class="mmpText" src="images/title_n1-2.png" alt="MMP" align="top"/>
        <div class="loginDiv">
            <form action="https://secure.bridgedeck.org/LoggedInHome.asp"  style="font-family:Calibri" method="post">
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Members Login</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Email" width="80px"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" width="80px"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="29"><input type="submit" value="Login" class="submit"></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would probably help to see all the html (including the DIV which is causing the problem).

Comment: The div is there, as you can see in the CSS - it shows up as "div" in view source, when you click inspect element and hover around the bottom of the menu items it shows up.  The rest of the page has no effect on this code as this is just an include.

Comment: Please post your (relevant) code in the question. Most people aren't going to follow urls.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Neograph.  I posted the two classes that seem to give me trouble, I just thought it would be easier if you could see for yourself where the overlap occurs.  I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre><code>
     #nav li.top {
      display: block;
      float: left;
      height: 35px;
      padding-left: 5px;
      padding-right: 5px;
     }
</code></pre>
```

change height on line 119 in pro_dropdown_n1.css

watch your gaps created with height.

Comment: Thank you for the response Alex.  However, this does not solve the issue.  I have tried various heights in this part of the code.

Comment: You changed something else. I tested that several times. I know you changed something else with it because when I set it back to 38px it doesnt even sometimes work like before. Undo your changes you added to mine, and simply add the height to 35px ONLY.

Comment: I checked for edits, I did not make any I am positive.  You had it working in Chrome, correct?

Comment: I changed it to 50 for kicks and it works fine. 38px isn't enough for all of the dropdowns.